# Easily convert string column to pl.datetime in Polars

Tags: python, python-polars

Consider a Polars data frame with a column of `str` type that indicates the date in the format `'27 July 2020'`. I would like to convert this column to the `polars.datetime` type, which is distinct from the Python standard `datetime`. The following code, using the standard `datetime` format, works but Polars does not recognise the values in the column as dates.

```
import polars as pl
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.read_csv('<some CSV file containing a column called 'event_date'>')
df = df.with_columns([   
        pl.col('event_date').apply(lambda x: x.replace(" ","-"))\
                            .apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%d-%B-%Y'))
])
```

Suppose we try to process `df` further to create a new column indicating the quarter of the year an event took place.

```
df = df.with_columns([
        pl.col('event_date').apply(lambda x: x.month)\
                            .apply(lambda x: 1 if x in range(1,4) else 2 if x in range(4,7) else 3 if x in range(7,10) else 4)\
                            .alias('quarter')
])
```

The code returns the following error because it qualifies `event_type` as `dtype Object("object")` and not as `datetime` or `polars.datetime`

```
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'dtype Object("object") not supported', src/series.rs:992:24
--- PyO3 is resuming a panic after fetching a PanicException from Python. ---
PanicException: Unwrapped panic from Python code
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**Update:** [`.str.to_datetime()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.str.to_datetime.html#polars.Expr.str.to_datetime) can be used as of polars [`v0.17.10`](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/releases/tag/py-0.17.10)

```
df = pl.from_repr("""
┌─────┬──────────────────┐
│ id  ┆ event_date       │
│ --- ┆ ---              │
│ i64 ┆ str              │
╞═════╪══════════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 27 July 2020     │
│ 2   ┆ 31 December 2020 │
└─────┴──────────────────┘
""")

df.with_columns(
   pl.col("event_date").str.to_datetime("%d %B %Y")
)
```

```
shape: (2, 2)
┌─────┬─────────────────────┐
│ id  ┆ event_date          │
│ --- ┆ ---                 │
│ i64 ┆ datetime[μs]        │
╞═════╪═════════════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 2020-07-27 00:00:00 │
│ 2   ┆ 2020-12-31 00:00:00 │
└─────┴─────────────────────┘
```

---

The easiest way to convert strings to Date/Datetime is to use Polars' own [`strptime`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.str.strptime.html) function (rather than the same-named function from Python's `datetime` module).

For example, let's start with this data.

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    'date_str': ["27 July 2020", "31 December 2020"]
})
print(df)
```

```
shape: (2, 1)
┌──────────────────┐
│ date_str         │
│ ---              │
│ str              │
╞══════════════════╡
│ 27 July 2020     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 31 December 2020 │
└──────────────────┘
```

To convert, use Polars' [strptime](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.str.strptime.html) function.

```py
df.with_columns(pl.col('date_str').str.strptime(pl.Date, fmt='%d %B %Y').cast(pl.Datetime))
```

```
shape: (2, 1)
┌─────────────────────┐
│ date_str            │
│ ---                 │
│ datetime[μs]        │
╞═════════════════════╡
│ 2020-07-27 00:00:00 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2020-12-31 00:00:00 │
└─────────────────────┘
```

Notice that we did not need to replace spaces with dashes.  I've cast the result as a Datetime (per your question), but you may be able to use a Date instead.

Currently, the `apply` method does not work when the return type is a python Date/Datetime object, but there is a [request](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/3022) for this.  That said, it's better to use Polars' `strptime`.  It will be much faster than calling python `datetime` code.

**Edit**: as of Polars `0.13.19`, the `apply` method will automatically convert Python date/datetime to Polars Date/Datetime.

Comment: for your df to reflect the changes assign the function to it: `df = df.with_colu....`

Comment: You’ll find the non-assignment to be common in Polars discussions, particularly when we just want to print a result, but not change the original DataFrame.  So instead of assigning and then issuing a print statement which is two lines, we simply don’t assign the value, which acts as an implicit print statement.

Comment: `from_repr` is pure witchcraft, thank you for bringing that up!

Comment: Is it possible to keep %d %B %Y format after casting to datetime data type?